# How to fix no audio on Parrot Sec 4.10

Tags: linux, audio, mate-desktop, parrotsec

I have no audio and I don't know why:
[image: Computer specs]

I tried:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

It returns:

```
sudo: alsa: command not found
```

Comment: What does `find / -name alsa` display?

Comment: a long list that says permission denied

/usr/share/alsa
/usr/share/sounds/alsa
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.7.0-2parrot2-amd64/include/config/thinkpad/acpi/alsa
find: ‘/var/cache/apparmor/ea9ed67a.0’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/apt/archives/partial’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/ldconfig’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/lighttpd’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/private’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/cache/lightdm’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/AccountsService/users’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/NetworkManager’: Permission denied

Comment: Try `sudo find / -name alsa`

Answer (score 1):

found the fix
changed:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"

from: /etc/default/grub

then: sudo update-grub